# Update panel in custom control is disappearing on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a custom control for the first time and I need some javascript to run as an initialization on the control. I've found that the only way I can get ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to execute on postback is if I tie it to an UpdatePanel. I added an update panel to my custom control and it will execute the javascript on the initial page load and for one postback but never again after that. I've narrowed the problem down to the fact that the update panel stops getting rendered to the page after the first postback. Everything else in the control gets rendered correctly except the update panel, which just disappears. The problem can be seen with this stripped down control.

```
public class SimpleTest : DataBoundControl
{
    private UpdatePanel _updatePanel;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        _updatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
        _updatePanel.ID = "testScriptUpdate";
        _updatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Always;
        Controls.Add(_updatePanel);
    }

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        _updatePanel.RenderControl(writer);
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        EnsureChildControls();
    }
}
```

And the button I'm using to do the postback is a simple

```
<button type="button" onclick="__doPostBack('','');" >PostBack</button>
```

If you inspect the page, the update panel will be there the first time but, after clicking the button, won't show up again. I feel that I must be missing some setting to make this work but after hours of fiddling with this I need to ask for help.

Comment: I've seen a similar issue some time ago, but it might help your case. Thing is, ASP.NET considers an object as `invisible` (`visible = false`) when _the object_ is implicitly set to invisible _or_ when it's _parent objects_ are set to invisible. Check if there are any parent objects (another panel or it's user control) set as invisible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but explicitly setting the visibility of both the update panel and/or the parent to true didn't change the output.

Comment: Do you call CreateChildControls each time you Page_Load? If not, you need to set its enableviewstate to true or the page will render without the control on each postback, since it is created dynamically and has no state.

Comment: I tried adding an explicit call to CreateChildControls and setting EnableViewState to true but no change in behavior.

Comment: I've never built a custom control, but I know that if a partial postback occurs due to a control outside an `UpdatePanel`, the only way controls inside the `UpdatePanel` can update is if the control outside the `UpdatePanel` is specified as an `<asp:AsyncPostbackTrigger>` in the `<Triggers>` section.  Don't know if this applies to your situation or not.

Comment: The update panel itself is disappearing after postback. There aren't any controls inside of it. I only have it in the control to execute javascript through, which works until it stops rendering.